Clarifications on BCNF decomposition and dependency-preserving

Given a relation schema, R = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O} with functional dependencies:
FD1: {A,B} -> {C,D}
FD2: {E} -> {F,G,J,K}
FD3: {F, G, I, K, M} -> {H}
FD4: {K} -> {L,M}
FD5: {M} -> {I}
FD6: {A, B, E} -> {N, O}

Identify how many different BCNF decompositions exist for this relation schema by
applying the BCNF decomposition algorithm (i.e. how many different sets of relation schemas and functional dependencies you obtain after applying the BCNF decomposition).

List all BCNF decompositions that are lossless and dependency-preserving.



For relation R to be in BCNF, all the functional dependencies that hold in R need to satisfy the property that the determinants are all superkeys of R (i.e. for R to be in BCNF, if X->Y holds in R then X must be a superkey of R).
The only candidate key is {A,B,E}, so FDs 1-5 are violating BCNF since their LHS cannot be superkeys. I decomposed R into a set of relations S that are in BCNF with the steps below:
S = {ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO}
S = {ABCD,ABEFGHIJKLMNO} // by using FD1
S = {ABCD, EFGJK, ABEHILMNO} // by using FD2
S = {ABCD, EFGJK, MI, ABEHLMNO} // by using FD5
// Return S as all relations are in BCNF
I repeated the steps above for different combinations. For example, rather than starting with FD1, I started with FD2, FD3, etc. However, it is tedious to do this and I may have left out some cases.
What is an easier way to find the number of BCNF decompositions?
I found 6 combinations that result in unique BCNF decompositions:
1: FD1 -> FD2 -> FD5
2: FD1 -> FD3 -> FD2 -> FD5
3: FD1 -> FD4 -> FD5
4: FD3 -> FD5 -> FD4 -> FD1 -> FD2
5: FD5 -> FD4 -> FD1 -> FD2
6: FD3 -> FD5 -> FD1 -> FD4 -> FD2
BCNF decompositions are lossless, but not necessarily dependency-preserving. The above 6 decompositions are all not dependency preserving.
What dependency-preserving cases have I missed?

Please do not cross post. Since this has been edited, voted on & commented on please delete the dba.se post.

Your (assignment's) "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a cover is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. See this answer.

"the BCNF decomposition algorithm" Which one? "What is an easier way" You haven't given any way. Explain the "way" you mean. Anyway you don't follow one, you just poke around a bit. "I found 6 combinations" This is not helpful. If you don't have a way, give what relevant things you know & ask re being stuck. If you came up with a way (like brute force) give & justify it. "I may have left out some cases" How, if you have a way & are following it? Why would another way help you if you can't correctly follow a way you have? "->" Please don't abuse symbols & terms, say what you mean.

"are all not dependency preserving" One of your decompositions is not in BCNF & some are in BCNF & preserve FDs.

Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Ask (only) re the 1st place you are stuck.  Put in all & only what is needed to ask it. Ask other questions in other posts. Yes-or-no questions are seldom useful & seldom asking for what is actually wanted. I edited yours. But one question still asks for a bare list--again, seldom useful & seldom asking for what is actually wanted. Ask what you actually want answered. [ask] [Help]
